# How to manage and differentiate literature reviews for different papers with related subject?

Tags: publications, plagiarism, literature-review

I wrote a research paper on a given topic. And now I'm writing a continuation for the same research. My question are :

- How to include the literature review of the previous paper in the current paper while avoiding plagiarism?
- How to differentiate the current literature review from the previous one?

Comment: When was the first paper published ? Are there papers of related subject written by other authors published after you published your first paper ?

Comment: The first paper is still in review by the journal.
Yes, new papers with related subjects were published  by other authors recently.

Answer (score 2):

First, it is absolutely acceptable to have significant overlap (**in terms of content**) between the two literature reviews. Of course, you need to avoid plagiarism. The best solution is to rewrite the literature review from scratch. By doing this, you can also reassess if all content from the original review is needed in the new paper and whether the order in which you present information makes sense for the new paper (but see below).

To distinguish the new from the original literature review, there are several things to address:

1. Most importantly, include a brief review of your first paper to highlight what was found there and use this to highlight why an additional paper is needed.
2. Your continuation will address questions not covered by your first paper. Make sure to include sufficient background on these new questions in your new literature review.
3. Add any relevant information that was published since your first paper.